# How to configure layout PT-BR on Ubuntu 22.04 running on a Macbook Pro 9,2 with US (English) ANSI keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook, macbook-pro

I've given up using Mac OS on my old Macbook Pro mid 2012 (model id:9,2), so I installed Ubuntu 22.04. But I speak Brazilian Portuguese, so I wanted to use PT-BR as my system language. However, my keyboard is US (English) ANSI, according to Apple's support page https://support.apple.com/pt-br/HT201794.

Here's a picture of my keyboard layout:

[Macbook Pro mid 2012 (9,2) Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU4Qs.jpg)

The problem is I can't at all configure it to work with this layout. When I configure it to use Brazilian Portuguese, it sets to the Brazilian Standard Layout, a.k.a. ABNT2, which has a dedicated key for 'Ç' and has the places of '~' and ''' swapped. Besides, I can't use ~, ^, or ' with other vowels as they are used in poruguese. They become separate characters.

For example, if I want to wtrite 'é' or 'ã' as is common in Portuguese, it becomes 'e and ~a, respectively.

How can I solve this problem? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* layout is commonly used by Brazilian Portuguese speaking users, and is probably a sensible choice given that your physical keyboard is intended for English (US).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @GunnarHjalmarsson! It helped a lot! I still have some work to do to write some specific characters, such as ç, but I could figure out which combination of keys to press to generate it!

Comment: Great. Then please put that solution in an answer. It's fine to answer your own question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying @Gunnar Hjalmarsson suggestion, it worked for me like a charm! Anyone who has the same problem can do this and it will work.